# Extract data from json with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, rjsonio

I have a long json file from which I want to extract the city name and its corresponding elevation. Result should be a list where column A holds the city name, column B the elevation.

Here some data for R:

```
l <- fromJSON('[{"_id": "CtNjHGG8asEvFyqsM","cronjobname": "Elev","cronjobid": "mmsibiZL4p42fL8jh",
"cronjobtyp": "importTestData","datasource": "importTestData","data": [{
 "Station": "New York","Elev":    300},{ "Station": "London","Elev":    35}],
"createdAt": "2016-04-30T22:10:11.342Z","createdBy": null,"modifiedAt": "2016-04-30T22:10:11.342Z","modifiedBy": null}]')
```

And that's what I came up with:

```
m <- lapply(
  l[[1]]$data, 
  function(x) c(x$Station['Station'], x$Elev['Elev'])
)
m <- do.call(rbind, m)
```

However, I know that this is not complete and should be `l[[1]]$data[[1]]$Station` to access the station, but I can't simply use `[[x]]$Station` unfortunately. What am I missing or do I need to put this into a loop to access multiple `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
  m<-lapply(
        l[[1]]$data, 
        function(x) c(x$Station, x$Elev)
  )
  m <- do.call(rbind, m)
  > m
  [,1]       [,2] 
  [1,] "New York" "300"
  [2,] "London"   "35"
```

Or you can use this:

```
  m <- do.call(rbind, l[[1]]$data)
  > m
  Station    Elev
  [1,] "New York" 300 
  [2,] "London"   35
```

The statement `x$Station['Station']`  equivalent to `l[[1]]$data[[1]]$Station['Station']` so there is nothing in it.